# Change the output of something using Add_filter in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am using [Tim Whitlock's Latest Tweets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/latest-tweets-widget/) plugin to display tweets.

I would like to modify the plugin's default output. I have found the below in line 137 of the plugin file:

```
$final = apply_filters('latest_tweets_render_tweet', $html, $date, $link, $tweet );
            if( $final === $html ){
                $final = '<p class="tweet-text">'.$html.'</p>'.
                         '<p class="tweet-details"><a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank">'.$date.'</a></p>';
            }
            $rendered[] = $final;
```

And have come up with this filter to attempt to change the output:

```
add_filter('latest_tweets_render_tweet', 'modified_tweets', 10);

function modified_tweets( $html, $date, $link, $tweet ) {

$final = '<div class="col-sm-4">'.
         '<p class="tweet-text2">'.$html.'</p>'.
         '<p class="tweet-details"><a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank">'.$date.'</a></p>'.
         '</div>';

         $rendered[] = $final;

};
```

However, the output remains the same. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to return that array, so add:-

```
return $rendered;
```

after this:-

```
$rendered[] = $final;
```

Comment: THanks. I'm getting a 'Missing argument 2' error now though. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Actually, the 4th parameter specifies how many arguments the function modified_tweets accepts,  bydefault its 1. 
So, update your add_filter function to:-
add_filter('latest_tweets_render_tweet', 'modified_tweets', 10, 4);

Answer (score 0):

As DWX mentioned, you're missing the `return`. But you don't need to return an array, the original code is expecting a string:

```
$my_final = '<div class="col-sm-4">'. $etcetera;
return $my_final;
```

And also add the number of arguments after the priority when adding the filter:

```
add_filter('latest_tweets_render_tweet', 'modified_tweets', 10, 4);
```